# C# - how to monitor transaction activity for a banking application

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, banking

I have been trying on a banking application code in which I want to monitor transaction activity where you read through a list of transaction records and return account nos that have exceeded the threshold amount for a given date.

For this I created a dummy text file using streamwriter where in I have the transaction records maintained spaced out with \t
For eg: AccountNumber\tTransactionDate\tTransactionAmount

When I read I am not sure how to split and collect distinct account nos for a given date and calculate the transaction amounts to further verify if its above the threshold amount.

Any help with this will be highly appreciated.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is there a reason you're using a tab delimited list rather than something like xml that C# has a much easier time serializing?

Comment: In general, your best bet here would be to go about deserializing the tab delimited file into a C# object. At least, that's my first instinct. I'll put together a little demo of what you would have to do.

Answer (score 1):

You could split out the tabs to an array using split on the string you've read.

```
String Instr =  "AccountNumber\tTransactionDate\tTransactionAmount";
char delim = '\t';
string[] array = Instr.Split(delim);
// array[0] = AccountNumber 
// array[1] = TransactionDate 
// array[2] = TransactionAmount
```

Answer (score 0):

To build upon what Steve said, I would personally be inclined to deserialize the text into an object. Doing something like what I have below....

Now, instead of having just an array of text you could have an array of objects whose properties are the right types. Lots easier to do a date comparison... add up all of the amounts for a particular account when they're in plain old objects. At least, for me it is.

As a side note, what I have below is a pretty bad idea to do. But if you're just stubbing something out to replace it with something like a database access layer in the future, this could work in the short term.

Edit: If you're going to be storing data in plain text files, it would be much better to store them in a format that C# can handle. Something like JSON, and then use Newtonsoft.Json to serialize / deserialize or XML and use System.Xml.Serialization to serialize / deserialize the data.

```
class Program
  {
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
      string srcfile = @"C:\Workspace\tmp\TestSTuff\bank\transactions.txt";
      string transactionstr;

      using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(srcfile, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
      {
        byte[] buffer = new byte[fs.Length];
        int numtoread = (int)fs.Length;
        int numread = 0;
        while (numtoread > 0)
        {
          int n = fs.Read(buffer, numread, numtoread);
          if (n == 0)
            break;
          numread += n;
          numtoread -= n;
        }
        transactionstr = Encoding.Default.GetString(buffer); 
      }

      char[] newline = { '\r','\n' };
      char delim = ',';
      string[] transactionstrs = transactionstr.Split(newline);

      List<Transaction> transactions = new List<Transaction>();
      foreach (var t in transactionstrs)
      {
        try
        {
          string[] fields = t.Split(delim);
          DateTime.Parse(fields[1]);
          transactions.Add(new Transaction
          {
            AccountNumber = int.Parse(fields[0]),
            TransactionDate = DateTime.Parse(fields[1]),
            TransactionAmount = double.Parse(fields[2])
          });
        }
        catch
        {
          continue;
        }
      }
    }
  }

  public class Transaction
  {
    public int AccountNumber { get; set; }
    public DateTime TransactionDate { get; set; }
    public double TransactionAmount { get; set; }
  }
```